# Regex to capture string inside single or double quotation marks

Tags: regex

I am writing a regular expression to parse lines containing labeled fields. The label appears before an equals sign, and the content appears after the equalts sign, enclosed in either single or double quotation marks. For most fields, the content is enclosed in single quotation marks. If the content of the field contains single quotation marks, then the field is enclosed in double quotation marks. E.g.:

```
J=''K='6'2='A'6='&JOBNAM#'P='&USERNAME#'O='1,1'7=''Q='ABC.JCLLIB(TEST1)'a="'D08/APPL'"U='1'S='*ALL'T='0'V='0'R='H'W='H'
```

My regex works, except with fields enclosed in double quotation marks.

```
([JK26PO7QaUSTVRW])\=(?:(?:\"([^"])*\")|(?:\'([^']*)\'))
```

[Test in Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/eJKwl0E1yrXnrA9X)

[Test in Regexr](http://regexr.com/3easb)

For fields like the one labeled *a* in the example above, *a="'D08/APPL'"*, the a is matched by capture group 1, and the trailing single quotation mark is captured by capture group 2. I want capture group 2 to capture *'D08/APPL'* in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it something like this you're after:

```
\w=(["'])((?:(?!\1).)*)\1
```

It matches, and captures, a quote - either a `'` or a `"`. Then it uses a negative look ahead to match any character **except** the quote from the first match. Finally a matching quote is matched ;)

Everything between the quotes get captured to the second group.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/f42lPM/1).

**Edit**

Checked your own attempt, and the only mistake is that you placed the quantifier for characters inside the `"`-quoted group outside the group parenthesis. I.e. the capture consist only of the last character **not** being a `"`. Try:

```
([JK26PO7QaUSTVRW])\=(?:(?:\"([^"]*)\")|(?:\'([^']*)\'))
                                  ^ ^
                                 /   \
                             Here     Not here
```

Comment: Perfect. Your approach using negative look ahead is more elegant. I modified it slightly so that I can print out the field labels.

   `(\w)=(["'])((?:(?!\2).)*)(\2)`

Comment: Glad to help. If you find the answer useful, you're always permitted to up-vote. Sometimes it's nice not to be [an unsung hero](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero) ;).

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<key>\w+)\=(?P<quote>['"])(?<value>.*?)(?P=quote)
```

This finds the label or "key"

```
(?<key>\w+)
```

This matches an equals sign

```
\=
```

This finds a single quote or a double quote, and keeps track of which

```
(?P<quote>['"])
```

This finds the value inside the quotes

```
(?<value>.*?)
```

This matches the opening quote (single or double)

```
(?P=quote)
```

https://regex101.com/r/f42lPM/1